# Try/Except error Python?

Tags: python, try-catch, except, try-except

The output of my code is supposed to look like:

Encipher:

```
Enter 1 to encipher or 2 to decipher: 1
Enter text you wish to encipher: My dog has fleas.
Enter the number of characters to shift: 7
The encrypted text is: Fr whz atl yextl.
```

Decipher:

```
Enter 1 to encipher or 2 to decipher: 2
Enter text you wish to decipher: Fr whz atl yextl.
The most likely shift is: 7
My dog has fleas.
```

So far I have this and I keep getting invalid syntax. I am confused on how to be able to type an answer in the output. It's supposed to be try/except with a while loop because it is a school assignment.

```
while True: 
    try: 
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        if num in [1,2]:
            break
        print "You have to enter 1 or 2, try again"

    if (num == 1):
        num = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
        num = int(raw_input('encipher'))
        print "Enter text to encipher"
        print "Enter the number of characters you want to shift" 


    elif (num == 2):
        num = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
        num = int(raw_input('decipher'))
        print "Enter text to decipher"
        print "Enter the number of characters you want to shift"
```

Comment: Is that the indentation you used in your program?

Comment: yes. I'm just starting python and the indentation confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't absolutely need to use a try/except, but if you want to try to do the conversion to integer right then and there, you could.  The main problem is that you don't have an except block anywhere.

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        if num in [1,2]:
            break
    except ValueError as e:
        print "You didn't enter a number.  Try again"
```

Comment: I think you should narrow this to `except ValueError`. Catching all exceptions may hide other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a `try-except` correctly.
The idea is to try a chunk of code; but if it runs into an error/exception, do something else.

```
while True: 
    try: 
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        if num in [1,2]:
            break
        print "You have to enter 1 or 2, try again"
```

In your script you are trying to take in an int that is in an array and you are handling a scenario in which it is not in your pre-defined list of options. However, you are not doing anything if their is an exception to that chunk of code.

To utilize the `try-except` do the following:

```
while True: 
    try: 
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        if num in [1,2]:
            break
        print "You have to enter 1 or 2, try again"
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```